# Como preencher automaticamente campos ao salvar objeto em banco

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tenho um sistema, em `ASP.NET MVC` que implementa uma forma de auditoria, que quando um usuário faz a inserção ou atualização de um objeto no banco de dados, algumas informações são salvas em uma tabela de auditoria de forma automática.

A interface, que quero implementar é está:

```
public interface IEntidade
{
    DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }
    String UsuarioCriacao { get; set; }
    DateTime UltimaModificacao { get; set; }
    String UsuarioModificacao { get; set; }
}
```

Tenho também, um exemplo de `SaveChanges();` em minha classe que herda de `DbContext`

```
public override int SaveChanges()
   {
        try
        {
            var currentTime = DateTime.Now;

            foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.Entity != null &&
                    typeof(IEntidadePrimitiva).IsAssignableFrom(e.Entity.GetType())))
            {
                if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
                {                       

                    if (entry.Property("DataCriacao") != null)
                    {
                        entry.Property("DataCriacao").CurrentValue = currentTime;
                    }
                    if (entry.Property("UsuarioCriacao") != null)
                    {
                        entry.Property("UsuarioCriacao").CurrentValue = HttpContext.Current != null ? HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name : "Usuario";
                    }
                }

                if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
                {
                    entry.Property("DataCriacao").IsModified = false;
                    entry.Property("UsuarioCriacao").IsModified = false;

                    if (entry.Property("UltimaModificacao") != null)
                    {
                        entry.Property("UltimaModificacao").CurrentValue = currentTime;
                    }
                    if (entry.Property("UsuarioModificacao") != null)
                    {
                        entry.Property("UsuarioModificacao").CurrentValue = HttpContext.Current != null ? HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name : "Usuario";
                    }
                }
            }

            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
                .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
                .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);

            var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);

            var exceptionsMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, "Os erros de validações são: ", fullErrorMessage);

            throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionsMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
        }
    }
```

Mas o que estou em dúvida, é sobre como implementar de fato, para que salve em uma tabela o usuário que fez a inserção ou atualização desse dados.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Repare que o código para salvar o usuário está aqui:

```
if (entry.Property("UsuarioModificacao") != null)
{
    entry.Property("UsuarioModificacao").CurrentValue = HttpContext.Current != null ? HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name : "Usuario";
}
```

O princípio é simples: se há uma tabela de auditoria global para o sistema, você pode mapeá-la assim:

```
public class Auditoria
{
    [Key]
    public int AuditoriaId { get; set; }
    public string EntidadeModificada { get; set; }
    public int IdentificadorEntidadeId { get; set; }
    public string NomeCampoModificado { get; set; }
    public string ValorAntigo { get; set; }
    public string ValorNovo { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataModificacao { get; set; }
    public string UsuarioModificacao { get; set; }
}
```

Aí pode pegar os campos que foram modificados desta forma:

```
        var camposModificados = context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where (t => t.State == EntityState.Modified)
        .Select (t => new {
            EntidadeModificada = t.Entity.GetType().Name,
            ValorAntigo = t.OriginalValues.PropertyNames.ToDictionary (pn => pn, pn => t.OriginalValues[pn]),
            ValorNovo = t.CurrentValues.PropertyNames.ToDictionary (pn => pn, pn => t.CurrentValues[pn]),
        });
```

Esta forma é o que chamamos de **auditoria incremental** ou **auditoria delta**, onde apenas as modificações são auditadas.

Há uma outra forma de auditoria em que cada entidade tem sua tabela dedicada de auditoria, com todos os campos da tabela original e mais alguns. Aí seria interessante você mudar sua interface para:

```
public interface IEntidade<TClasseAuditada>
    where TClasseAuditada: class
{
    DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }
    String UsuarioCriacao { get; set; }
    DateTime? UltimaModificacao { get; set; }
    String UsuarioModificacao { get; set; }
}
```

Sua classe vai ser algo como:

```
public class MinhaClasse : IEntidade<MinhaClasseAuditoria> { ... }
public class MinhaClasseAuditoria { /* Mesmos campos de MinhaClasse, com usuário e data de modificação */ }
```

Neste caso, você teria que fazer o contexto criar dinamicamente a classe de auditoria, assim:

## `SeuContexto.cs`, `SaveChanges()` e `SaveChangesAsync()`

```
foreach (var entidade in ChangeTracker.Entries())
{
    var tipoTabelaAuditoria = entidade.Entity.GetType().GetInterfaces()[0].GenericTypeArguments[0];
    var registroTabelaAuditoria = Activator.CreateInstance(tipoTabelaAuditoria);

    // Isto aqui é lento, mas serve como exemplo. 
    // Depois procure trocar por FastMember ou alguma outra estratégia de cópia.
    foreach (var propriedade in entidade.Entity.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        registroTabelaAuditoria.GetType()
                               .GetProperty(propriedade.Name)
                               .SetValue(registroTabelaAuditoria, entidade.Entity.GetType().GetProperty(propriedade.Name).GetValue(entidade.Entity, null));
    }

    /* Salve aqui usuário e data */
    this.Set(registroTabelaAuditoria.GetType()).Add(registroTabelaAuditoria);
}
```

Isto é o que chamamos de **auditoria espelho**.

Comment: Então a classe `public override int SaveChanges()` que usei na pergunta não é utilizada?

Comment: É usada sim. O código da auditoria espelho vai dentro dele.