# O que faz cada coisa neste método? (Auditoria Espelho no Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Bem, acompanhando esta excelente [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/169166/61561) do Cigano, onde ele implementa uma forma de **Auditoria Espelho**, onde é implementado no `DbSaveChanges()` o seguinte método:

```
//Laço de repetição em ChangeTracker.Entries. Mas o que é ele? 
foreach (var entidade in ChangeTracker.Entries())
{
    // ** É possível explicar de forma sucinta o que está acontecendo aqui?
    var tipoTabelaAuditoria = entidade.GetType().GetInterfaces()[0].GenericTypeArguments[0];
    var registroTabelaAuditoria = Activator.CreateInstance(tipoTabelaAuditoria);

    // Isto aqui é lento, mas serve como exemplo. 
    // Depois procure trocar por FastMember ou alguma outra estratégia de cópia.
    // ** E aqui ?
    foreach (var propriedade in entidade.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        registroTabelaAuditoria.GetType()
                               .GetProperty(propriedade.Name)
                               .SetValue(registroTabelaAuditoria, entidade.GetType().GetProperty(propriedade.Name).GetValue(entidade, null));
    }

    /* Salve aqui usuário e data */
    this.Set(registroTabelaAuditoria.GetType()).Add(registroTabelaAuditoria);
```

Bem, deixei em comentários no código onde sinto dúvidas, mas deixo aqui algumas questões afim de objetivar mais a pergunta.

O que é `ChangeTracker.Entries()` ?

O que faz está linha `var tipoTabelaAuditoria = entidade.GetType().GetInterfaces()[0].GenericTypeArguments[0];` ?

Aqui, sei que ele está pegando as propriedades dos tipos nas propriedades, mas se possível explicar de uma forma melhor.

```
foreach (var propriedade in entidade.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    registroTabelaAuditoria.GetType()
          .GetProperty(propriedade.Name)
          .SetValue(registroTabelaAuditoria, entidade.GetType().GetProperty(propriedade.Name).GetValue(entidade, null));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> O que é ChangeTracker.Entries()?

São as entidades que o contexto observou que possuem alguma alteração em relação ao registro original do banco de dados.

> O que faz esta linha `var tipoTabelaAuditoria = entidade.GetType().GetInterfaces()[0].GenericTypeArguments[0];`?

Esta linha pega o tipo de `TClasseAuditada` declarado na classe que implementa `IEntidade<TClasseAuditada>`. Por exemplo:

```
public class MinhaClasse : IEntidade<MinhaClasseAuditoria> { ... }
```

O retorno seria o mesmo que `typeof(MinhaClasseAuditoria)`.

> Aqui, sei que ele está pegando as propriedades dos tipos nas propriedades, mas se possível explicar de uma forma melhor.

Melhor dizendo, os valores de cada propriedade da tabela a ser auditada, e copiando estes valores para a tabela de auditoria.